# Distributed Computing with Java and Spring should I use Messaging, Web Services or EJB?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, ejb

I am working in a firm that is new to java and I am the only java programmer and I need to write about 10 systems within a few months.. The firm has 2 other programmers that know basic java. Not Spring or anything like that.

The firm has User Data in LDAP, MySQL and on the AS/400. I am trying to think of some easy way to work with the 2 Jr Programmers. I was thinking about making them using Messaging, Web Services or EJB call for all the hard to get data.

Let them do the front-ends with Java and Springs and then do calls to web services or EJBs.

I would like to hear some of the best approach on this and the best ways.. All of the projects are web applications.

Should I use Web services or EJBs?

Answer (score 0):

Web Services will make it more losely coupled and easier if you need integrate it with different systems (e.g. data needs to be accessed by .NET code, by pre-existing apps, etc.).

EJB will not be as clean, and will be more painful if you need to access it from something other than Java. But if you're staying within Java, EJB will be more performant than Web Services, the overhead will be smaller, it will probably be quicker.

Messaging seems like an in-between solution to me: the advantages of both approaches.

Comment: We are only going to be doing java so it sounds like you are in VOTE for the EJB's.  Is that try?

Comment: Now for the 2nd part.. If I use EJB... Should I use Spring JDBCTemple and Hiberante for data access within EJBS

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use Camel as an EIP (enterprise integration pattern) provider backed by messaging.

This is a prime use case for Camel, it's well suited to tranparently handle distributed patterns across platforms.

Camel + Spring + ActiveMQ make a great set.